# Avoid login (JAAS) every time I change path (and it generates a new session)

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, session-cookies, jaas

I've configured my Java EE app to use declarative security with JAAS (I've even implemented a custom LoginModule). The problem is that every time I change the url path (e.g. from http://mysite/restricted to http://mysite/restricted/configs), the system asks me to login again!!!!

After searching a little I found out that a new Session is being created every time I change the directory (there are cookies for each path). So I guess that the authentication is done for the session (seems obvious). But... how do I solve this? I need subdirectories to apply security by linking them with roles (role X can access /restricted/some-function/*). Also, I need that some roles (e.g. Manager) have access to all subdirectories without needing to login everytime.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the path of your cookies to `/`.

For Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html (Search for `sessionCookiePath`.)

Comment: Great! Thanks! But... I can't find it on JBoss AS7. Do you have any ideas? I've tried as this guy did, without success: http://community.jboss.org/thread/170235

Comment: Have you deleted your existing cookies?

Comment: of course... I've repackaged everything, restarted the server, redeployed, deleted existing cookies and tested everything again. Should it work with the servlet 3.0 web.xml's elements cited on the post? I've enabled "ALL" logs also, to see if there was any error. And there wasn't.

Comment: The `<cookie-config>` / `<path>/</path>` works for me with Tomcat 7. (I don't have JBoss.)

Comment: Just tested on JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final (I was using 7.0.0.Final) and it works!!! I've tried on 7.0.0.Final again and confirmed, there really is a bug on that version. Anyway, the solution is to use the web.xml's Servlet 3.0 configuration. Thank you, palacsint!